# use of hidden field for checkboxes in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, checkbox, cakephp-1.3, hidden-fields

What is the use of hidden fields for checkbox in cakePHP??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's so there's always *some* data submitted for the field, even if the box is not checked. This becomes especially important if you're using the [SecurityComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1296/Security-Component). You can turn it off by setting `'hiddenField' => false` as an option.

Comment: It was a real aha! moment for me when I realized why cake did this.  It just makes your backend code much nicer, when you can check for == 0 rather than if the variable is set, then checking its value.

Comment: but it gets problem when i try save with HABTM relations :(
it also inserts the data with value 0

Comment: @RSK In that case you can either `array_filter` the values in your controller, or use the `'hiddenField' => false`.